# Need advice from class A players?

Tags: tactics, rating, preparation

How much opening preparation does a 1800-1900(UCSF) player need and how to achieve that?
Also, do you need class A tactics rating to reach class A chess ranking?

Comment: What do you mean by "need"? How would you quantify "opening preparation" in a meaningful way? Is chess 99% tactics from your point of view?

Comment: You need Class A tactics, Class A strategy and so on...

Comment: @Annatar By opening preparation i meant knowing  response to opponents every move and Yes.

Comment: @bretlee So ... number of responses memorized?

Comment: The opening preparation at this level should not just involve learning concrete lines. At this point I think it's appropriate for a player to start asking themselves questions about their chess. What kinds of positions do they like/dislike? Using this, the player should see whether the openings they play actually fit their preferred style of play (balanced/unbalanced, tactical/slow, solid/wild, etc.). This way you could purge openings from your repertoire that are not a good fit, and replace them with something more proper for you.